# How to include the Indicate or Notify ability for BLE characteristic using C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10-universal, gatt

I am trying to include the **Indicate** or **Notify** ability for BLE characteristic using C# in Visual Studio 2017 Universal Windows Platform, in order to subscribe to **ValueChanged** event/add **ValueChanged** event to GattCharacteristic as shown in the following code:

```
characteristic.ValueChanged += Oncharacteristic_ValueChanged;
```

I can find many tutorials how to do so in Android Studio or using Java, but I am **UNABLE** to find it in C#.

I will be extremely happy if anyone could help me on this.

Comment: Have you googled? This is the first that came up for me https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/blegatt2

Comment: To give a meaningful answer we need to know  what you have done so far and the windows 10 version you target.
I could give you an example, but without more information it can be too much or too little to help.